# iphone html5 app (local database, external subscriptions)

Tags: iphone, database, html, app-store

I am looking to go to html5 craze, for iphone apps.

Can I use a uiwebview control to view an html5 app (javascript/jquery) that resides native, so that it can use an sqlite prepopulated in my app (first it's being downloaded from web)?

Secondly, can I use (generally, even in UI Native apps) an html5 inappstore (custom made) to purchase subscription for my apps?

Comment: Yes, you can. The code to effectively do so, however, is not simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think, yes, your HTML5 app can communicate with the apps' sqlite DB provided that it has access to sqlite DB's path.